# RegExp.Test always returning false

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following code at JSfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ACG2D/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.testThis').click(function() {
        $('.regexValidation').each(function() {
            if ($(this).val() != "" || $(this).val() != null) {
                // Check the regex
                var expression = new RegExp('/^[0-9a-z_]+$/i');
                var myVal = $(this).val();
                if (expression.test(myVal) == true) {
                    // All is okay
                    alert("OK");
                } else {
                    alert("Error");
                }
            }
        });
    });    
});
```

The intended plan is to only let alphanumeric and underscores through. Disallowing spaces and punctuation etc.

I can't figure out why this is going wrong, but it always returns false for the test.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong.

Change it to `var expression = /^[0-9a-z_]+$/i;`

Unlike PHP, Javascript supports regex *literals* the syntax `/.../` creates a `RegExp` object.

The `RegExp` constructor takes a regex as a string, without separators.
Therefore, you could also write `new RegExp('^[0-9a-z_]+$', 'i')`

Comment: Well.. You learn something new every day! I thought the lack of quotes would of cause JS to throw errors, but obviously not. Thanks for the answer and explanation.

Comment: Thanks, this save me, but also, you should remove spaces in each literal. I was try to do this: [ #, % ] but always returned false. Then th real expression is without space, it means: [#,%]. I Hope this helps other in the future. (y)

Answer (score 10):

Remove quotes from your RegExp:

```
var expression = new RegExp(/^[0-9a-z_]+$/i);
```

Answer (score 2):

Take out the quotes like this: `new RegExp(/^[0-9a-z_]+$/i);`

Comment: @Igor Dymov and @Mrchief: Is there any advantage to use `new RegExp(/ /)` instead of `/ /`?

Answer (score 0):

use  slash "/" instead of quotes, at the beginning  and end of the regular expression.

for your code, it should be like this -

`var expression = new RegExp(/^[0-9a-z_]+$/i);`